# Clojure code, tinkering with :main

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to run the following [code](https://gist.github.com/mjg123/1315792).

Below are the steps I took:

```
$ lein new app latinsq
```

I then modified project.clj as follows:

```
    (defproject latinsq "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main latinsq.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

and /latinsq/src/latinsq/core.clj

```
(ns latinsq.core
  (:use [clojure.set :only (difference)]))


(defn replace-at
  "in string s, replaces character at index p with c"
  [s p c]
  (str
   (.substring s 0 p)
   c
   (.substring s (inc p))))

; memoized function to save time on sqrt calls
(def sqrt (memoize (fn [x] (Math/sqrt x))))


(defn candidates
  "assuming that the position pos is empty in sq, return those values that it might be"
  [pos sq]

  (let [sq-size (int (sqrt (count sq)))]

                    ; set difference between...
    (difference
                    ; ...all the possible values...
     (set (map #(first (str %)) (range 1 (inc sq-size))))

                    ; ...and the set of...
     (into #{}
       (concat
                    ; ...those in the same column...
        (map #(get sq %)
         (range (rem pos sq-size)
            (count sq)
            sq-size))
                    ; ...and those in the same row.
        (map #(get sq %)
         (map #(+ % (- pos (rem pos sq-size)))
              (range 0 sq-size))))))))




(defn latinsq
  "encode your partial-square as a string like 1--1
   this fn returns a lazy sequence of all solutions"
  [sq]
                    ; Find the first empty square
  (let [empty-pos (.indexOf sq "-")]

                    ; if none, we don't need to do anything
    (if (= -1 empty-pos)
      (list sq)

                    ; else make a lazy sequence of...
      (lazy-seq
                    ; ...the concatenation of all the results of...
       (apply concat
                    ; ...using "map" to recurse, filling in the empty
                    ; square with...
          (map #(latinsq (replace-at sq empty-pos %))

                    ; ...each possible value in turn
           (candidates empty-pos sq)))))))




;; So, now some examples

(time
 (latinsq "123------"))
;; "Elapsed time: 0.045368 msecs"
;; ("123231312" "123312231")

(time
 (latinsq "12---31--------4"))
;; "Elapsed time: 0.068511 msecs"
;; ("1243431224313124" "1243431234212134")


;; A bit harder, an empty 5x5 grid
;; has 161280 solutions according to
;; http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html
(time
 (count (latinsq "-------------------------")))
;; "Elapsed time: 36980.759177 msecs"   <--- a bit slow
;; 161280


;; Having made sure that our function returns a lazy seq
;; the whole result can be treated lazily, so to find just one
;; solution to the 5x5 grid:
(time
 (first (latinsq "-------------------------")))
;; "Elapsed time: 0.985559 msecs"       <--- not slow
;; "1234521453345124523153124"

;; first 3 of 5524751496156892842531225600 solutions for a 9x9 grid
(time 
 (take 3 (latinsq "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------")))
;; "Elapsed time: 0.075874 msecs"
;; ("123456789214365897341278956432189675567891234658917342789523461896742513975634128"
;;  "123456789214365897341278956432189675567891234658917342789523461975634128896742513"
;;  "123456789214365897341278956432189675567891234658917342789524163896743521975632418")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Cannot find anything to run for: latinsq.core, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4810859530587029884.clj:1:73)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot find anything to run for: latinsq.core
        at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init4810859530587029884.clj:1)
        at user$eval5.invoke(form-init4810859530587029884.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        ... 14 more
```

From the research I have done, the issue is caused by the name on :main.  I've tinkered with this a few times and I have not been able to get this to work.  Is this because "latinsq" is showing up too many times in the directory tree?  Or, am I misunderstanding how to run the code.

Alternatively, when I finally get it to run, the only output is:

```
"Elapsed time: 0.468492 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.0796 msecs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define `-main` function - this one is automatically generated by leiningen in core namespace.
You also didn't specify how you try to run the application, but I assume you just invoke `lein run`.
As long as you add `-main` function to your namespace it should work.
I also recommend wrapping the `latinsq` function invocations into another function to avoid evaluating them when namespace is loaded.

Btw. this is the full output that I got (using unmodified `-main` generated by leiningen:

`lein run
"Elapsed time: 0.183692 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.055872 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 68742.261628 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1.361745 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.045366 msecs"
Hello, World!`

Comment: This leads me to two questions.  The first, how do I/where do I use the -main.  I placed it in various locations to try to get some context about it.  Secondly, shouldn't there be some sort of string output?  The  string output is what I'm most interested it.

Comment: Also I did just use lein run.

Comment: @emka 

1. As I said, the `-main` function is automatically generated in `core` namespace, it looks like this: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L205

2. I'm not sure what you mean by "string output" but if you want to get output on command line you just need to write to standard output (presumably with `println` function)